# Как узнать в каких беседах состоит тот или иной пользователь через бота. vk api php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

работаю с callback api.
Вообще новичок в php так и в ботах для вк.
Я хочу научить своего бота узнавать в каких беседах состоит тот или иной пользователь и последующего кика из всех бесед через личку бота или же из одной из бесед.
Покажу наглядно
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил эту проблему таким образом.
В теории - есть два варианта создания кика из всех бесед.
1 - Сделать цикл,который проверит в каких беседах состоит человек - примерно от 1 беседы до 100,В зависимости от популярности бота или просто сделать проверку на ошибку,которая говорит про то,что такой беседы не существует и цикл будет остановлен. Так-же в этом цикле сделать проверку на возможность администрировать в беседе у пользователя,который инициирует кик.

2 - сделать параметр в настройке бесед и в ручном формате включать/выключать кик. - этот вариант я выбрал.

https://github.com/Leeeky/kickall.git - тут код,потому-что сюда не помещался,в коде все описал подробно.